# How to pass a method name as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, methods, stream

**Is there a way to parameterize  a method name?**

**Example**:

```
JournalLine {

    BigDecimal ccyAmount;
    BigDecimal lcyAmount;
    BigDecimal rptAmount;
   
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

***Original (working)***

```
// Calculate totals
BigDecimal totalCcyAmount = journalLines.stream()
                                        .map(journalLine -> journalLine.getCcyAmount())
                                        .reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
                                        .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);

BigDecimal totalLclAmount = journalLines.stream()
                                       .map(journalLine -> journalLine.getLclAmount())
                                       .reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
                                       .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);

BigDecimal totalRptAmount = journalLines.stream()
                                        .map(journalLine -> journalLine.getRptAmount())
                                        .reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
                                        .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

This duplication is used in different locations of the application. Not always together.

***Is there a way to do something like:***

```
//Calculate totals and pass the method name
BigDecimal totalCcyAmount = getTotal(journalLines, "getCcyAmount");
BigDecimal totallclAmount = getTotal(journalLines, "getCcyAmount");
BigDecimal totalRptAmount = getTotal(journalLines, "getCcyAmount");
                                        
public BigDecimal getTotal( List<JournalLine> journalLines, String METHOD_NAME) {
    return journalLines.stream()
                         .map(journalLine -> journalLine.METHOD_NAME)
                         .reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
                         .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

I want to pass METHOD_NAME (getCcyAmount() or getLcyAmount() or getRptAmount ())
or use a different approach to avoid duplication of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using reflection, your best choice is probably passing a `FunctionalInterface` to the method:

Method call:

```
getTotal(journalLines, JournalLine::getCcyAmount);
```

and the method looks like this:

```
public BigDecimal getTotal(List<JournalLine> journalLines,
        Function<JournalLine, BigDecimal> function) {
    return journalLines.stream().map(function).reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
            .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

If you are really fixed on using a `String` as method argument, you wont get around using reflection. And that is where it becomes ugly, codewise:

```
private static BigDecimal getTotal(List<JournalLine> journalLines, String methodName) {
    Method method;
    try {
        method = JournalLine.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e2);
    }
    return journalLines.stream().map(e -> {
        try {
            return (BigDecimal) method.invoke(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e1);
        }
    }).reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b)).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
}
```

This would then work by calling

```
getTotal(list, "getCcyAmount");
```

However, you are way more prone to errors, by e.g. having a typo in your methodname string. The compiler can't even tell you before running into an error, as it is just a String, until the reflection starts.

---

Overall I suggest using `FunctionalInterface`s over reflection. Not only is the code less cluttered, but also you have the support of the compiler while coding.